# setTimeout - how to avoid using string for callback?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

When using `setTimeout`, you have to put the code you want to execute into a string:

```
setTimeout('alert("foobar!");', 1000);
```

However, I want to execute a function to which I have a reference in a variable. I want to be able to do this:

```
var myGreatFunction = function() { alert("foobar!"); };
// ...
setTimeout('myGreatFunction();', 1000);
```

(Though in real life, the alert is a lengthier bit of code and `myGreatFunction` gets passed around as a parameter to other functions, within which the `setTimeout` is called.)

Of course, when the timeout triggers, `myGreatFunction` isn't a recognised function so it doesn't execute.

I wish javascript let me do this, but it doesn't:

```
setTimeout(function() { myGreatFunction(); }, 1000);
```

Is there a nice way round this?

Comment: "When using setTimeout, you have to put the code you want to execute into a string" You most certainly do not... in fact, you _should not_.

Comment: @Tomalak - yes, you're right. See the comment on Kirtan's answer... :/

Comment: Actually I saw it; just wanted to be explicit here for the sake of anyone else who may see the question :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you don't need to call `myGreatFunction` with any arguments, you should be able to pass `setTimeout` a function reference:

```
setTimeout(myGreatFunction, 1000);
```

Also, you should always avoid passing `setTimeout` code that it needs to evaluate (which is what happens when you wrap the code in quotes). Instead, wrap the code in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Code here...
}, 1000);
```

See the [setTimeout page at the Mozilla Development Centre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Syntax) for more information.

Steve

Answer (score 14):

Who said that it doesn't let you do it?

It does, the code -

```
setTimeout(function() { myFunction(); }, 1000);
```

is perfectly valid.

Comment: Haha - yes, you're right. An unrelated bug meant it appeared my function wasn't being called when actually it was. This leaves me in the slightly embarrassing position of wanting to down-vote my own question...