# What's the equivalent of Java's Thread.sleep() in JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript

What's the equivalent of Java's `Thread.sleep()` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The simple answer is that there is no such function.

The closest thing you have is:

```
var millisecondsToWait = 500;
setTimeout(function() {
    // Whatever you want to do after the wait
}, millisecondsToWait);
```

Note that you *especially* don't want to busy-wait (e.g. in a spin loop), since your browser is almost certainly executing your JavaScript in a single-threaded environment.

Here are a couple of other SO questions that deal with threads in JavaScript:

- [JavaScript and Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036/javascript-and-threads)
- [Why doesn't JavaScript support multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading)

And this question may also be helpful:

- [setTimeout - how to avoid using string for callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797115/javascript-settimeout-without-putting-code-into-a-string)

Comment: (+1) look at setTimeout() and setInterval() in javascript

Comment: To promote good coding practices, it might be best to insert a semi-colon after "500" and initialise "millisecondsToWait" in the code sample (e.g. by preceding it with "var ") (this way, if someone copies and pastes the sample, they won't end up with an implied global).

Comment: Good catch, Steve.  I've edited my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: ES6 will have a new operator `yield` which can be used to "simulate" threads. See http://taskjs.org/ for an example library.

Comment: Using "setTimeout" will not stop the javascript thread and wait. Its only when the call stack is empty that the counting starts. But it depends on your intention which approach you want to use.

Answer (score 92):

Try with this code. I hope it's useful for you.

```
function sleep(seconds) 
{
  var e = new Date().getTime() + (seconds * 1000);
  while (new Date().getTime() <= e) {}
}
```

Comment: does exactly what it is supposed to

Comment: This doesn't put the thread to sleep, it just consumes the thread with wasteful calculation that is likely to block the UI. Not recommended.

Comment: That's a "busy wait" a.k.a you are "burning the thread"

Comment: For my unit testing purposes its useful. Surely, not for production.

Comment: "thread.distract"

Comment: This is a very bad idea.

Comment: Whatever you were doing was wrong.

Comment: It works in the same way as Thread.sleep in JAVA. Although never a good choice to implement something in production, but it answers the question perfectly.

Comment: Complete browser tab is Hung. Not recommended solution. Please remove it.

Comment: This is the equivalaent of
`
While (CurrentTime < TimeA){
    Thread.Sleep(0);
}
`

Comment: Don't understand how this got so many upvotes. Don't use it. See @Richrd answer.

Comment: @bruno.almeida because it is the correct answer. Thread.Sleep() makes the thread hang for the given timeout, nothing else processes on that thread. This does the exact same thing.

Comment: @Josh It doesn't, though. `Thread.sleep()` *sleeps* a thread, consuming essentially zero resources. This is the opposite of that: the thread doesn't sleep and it burns CPU in a very tight loop.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes this is true from a resource use perspective, but from a code flow execution perspective this is better than the accepted answer at simulating a thread.sleep(). Consider the case of a webworker processing its queue of messages, the accepted answer results in the worker moving on to the next message while the previous is still waiting on the timeout callback. The thread is not functionally asleep as it is handling other message. This answer actually prevents the thread from moving on to do other work.

Comment: @Josh :shrug: That sounds more like an issue with the queue consumer; if it doesn’t have a way to throttle itself and/or it isn’t callback-/promise-driven there’s already a potential problem. But this is orthogonal to the question, and my comment. Busy loops in JS are a problem because they have direct impact on system behavior. Are there isolated cases where they’re ok(-ish)? Sure.

Comment: In JavaScript, all stuff that gets executed gets executed (in theory) on a single thread. Sitting and looping while doing nothing until enough time passes blocks the event loop. `Thread.sleep()` in Java doesn't block other threads from executing, while it sort of has the effect of preventing anything else from executing in JavaScript. Which is why the solution proposed by this answer is neither useful, in most situations, nor advisable. You expect something to happen, while you sleep, and it won't.

Answer (score 84):

Assuming you're able to use ECMAScript 2017 you can emulate similar behaviour by using async/await and setTimeout. Here's an example sleep function:

```
async function sleep(msec) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, msec));
}
```

You can then use the sleep function in any other async function like this:

```
async function testSleep() {
    console.log("Waiting for 1 second...");
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log("Waiting done."); // Called 1 second after the first console.log
}
```

This is nice because it avoids needing a callback. The down side is that it can only be used in async functions. Behind the scenes the testSleep function is paused, and after the sleep completes it is resumed.

From MDN:

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until  a
>   Promise is fulfilled or rejected, and to resume execution of the async
>   function after fulfillment.

For a full explanation see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: this is the recommend approach in 2017

Comment: And in 2020 as well :)

Answer (score 10):

For Best solution, Use async/await statement for ecma script 2017

**await can use only inside of async function**

```
function sleep(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, time || 1000);
    });
}

await sleep(10000); //this method wait for 10 sec.
```

***Note : async / await not actualy stoped thread like Thread.sleep but simulate it***

Comment: Copying other answers is not nice

Answer (score 8):

There's no direct equivalent, as it'd pause a webpage.  However there is a [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_settimeout.asp), e.g.:

```
function doSomething() {
  thing = thing + 1;
  setTimeout(doSomething, 500);
}
```

Closure example (thanks Daniel):

```
function doSomething(val) {
  thing = thing + 1;
  setTimeout(function() { doSomething(val) }, 500);
}
```

The second argument is milliseconds before firing, you can use this for time events or waiting before performing an operation.

**Edit:**  Updated based on comments for a cleaner result.

Answer (score 5):

You can either write a spin loop (a loop that just loops for a long period of time performing some sort of computation to delay the function) or use:

```
setTimeout("Func1()", 3000);
```

This will call 'Func1()' after 3 seconds.

Edit:

Credit goes to the commenters, but you can pass anonymous functions to setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   //Do some stuff here
}, 3000);
```

This is much more efficient and does not invoke javascript's eval function.

Comment: I want the current thread to go for waiting state for specified number of seconds

Comment: Spinning a loop cause High CPU utilization.

Comment: I'd prefer to provide the function directly as an argument instead of quoting the function name: setTimeout( function() { ... }, 3000 );

Comment: You should *never* quote the first parameter for setTimeout—pass an anonymous function or a function reference. The corrected version is: setTimeout(Func1, 3000);

Comment: (Quoting the first parameter of setTimeout invokes "eval()" unnecessarily.)

Comment: @Steve, if you want to pass any parameters to the method, you really don't have that option, you must quote.

Comment: @Nick: No, if you want to pass parameters, you use a closure.

Answer (score 4):

setTimeout would not hold and resume on your own thread however Thread.sleep does. There is no actual equal in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can use the setInterval function, to call a particular function, after the specified number of milliseconds. Just do a google for the setInterval prototype.I don't quite recollect it.

Answer (score -1):

This eventually helped me:

```
    var x = 0;
    var buttonText = 'LOADING';

    $('#startbutton').click(function(){
        $(this).text(buttonText);
        window.setTimeout(addDotToButton,2000);
    })

    function addDotToButton(){
        x++;
        buttonText += '.';
        $('#startbutton').text(buttonText);

        if (x < 4) window.setTimeout(addDotToButton, 2000);
        else location.reload(true);
    }
```

Comment: setTimeout was already mentioned a looong time ago. and the rest of the code has nothing to do with the question.