# Add delay between 'for' loop iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement basic 60 sec counter(A `p` element with id`counter`), that is triggered after a button(`counter_start()`) is pressed.But I want delay of 1 sec between this and make sure this updates in browser window in real-time

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function counter_start(){
        x=0
        for(i=0;i<60;i++){
        x++;
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=x;

         }
     }


    </script>
```

P.S: There might be other simple methods of implementing a timer.But it's not about timer...actually I'm a student and trying to figure out the architecture and mechanism of this.
EDIT: please post tested versions of the code, as some of em' posted below DO NOT update in real time

Comment: You cant delay a for loop in and of itself, you will have to implement your own version of the for loop.

Comment: You should accept Parth's answer. All you need to do is replace `alert(i)` with `document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=i`

Answer (score 3):

Try this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/H8egV/41/)
Hope it will work for u

**JS**

```
 for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
   {
   (function(i){
       setTimeout(function(){
         alert(i);
     }, 1000 * i);
   }(i));
}
```

Comment: This method proves a good understanding of the language. Nice

Answer (score 1):

Javascript operates synchronously in the browser.

You need to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to schedule the for loop's body to be called every second. I'm using `setTimeout` in the below example for easier "garbage collection"; we will never reschedule the tick to happen after we don't need to update things anymore.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var counter = 0;

function counter_tick() {
    if(counter < 60) {
        counter++;
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
        setTimeout(counter_tick, 1000); // Schedule next tick.
    }
}

function counter_start() {
    counter_tick(); // First update, also schedules next tick to happen.
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to pause the current thread, which [isn't possible in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447407/whats-the-equivalent-of-javas-thread-sleep-in-javascript) and would probably be a bad idea anyway (the user's browser would lock up while the thread was paused).

A [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) is really the way to go with this, otherwise you are fighting the way the language is intended to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `sleep`-function in JS. But you can use `window.setTimeout` to call a function in given intervals:

```
function counter_start(){
    // get current value
    var value = document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML*1;
    // leave function if 60 is reached
    if(value == 60) {
         return;
    }
    // set the innerHTML to the last value + 1
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML=value+1;
    // call next iteration
    window.setTimeout(function(){counter_start()}, 100);
}

counter_start();
```

[JSFiddle-Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ttdm48g9/)

Comment: Why do you have counter_start() inside of its own function? Should just be window.setTimeout(counter_start, 100);

Answer (score 0):

For-loops run to completion, so you wouldn't usually use one for this.
You just need a timer and a variable to increment:

```js
var maketimer = function(){
    var tick = 0,
        interval_ms = 1000,
        limit = 10,
        id;
    return {
        start: function(){
            var timer = this;
            console.log('start');
            id = setInterval(function(){
                if(tick === limit){
                    timer.stop();
                    timer.reset();
                    return;
                }
                tick += 1;
                console.log(tick);
            }, interval_ms);
        },
        stop: function(){
            console.log('stop');
            clearInterval(id);
        },
        reset: function(){
            console.log('reset');
            tick = 0;
        }
    };
};

var t = maketimer();
t.start();
```

If you really need to use a for-loop, then you could use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). They're part of the proposed ES6 spec., and you'll need Firefox 26+ to try this out. However the only point of doing this would be to learn about generator functions.

```js
var maketimer = function(){
    var interval_ms = 1000,
        limit = 10,
        id,
        loop,
        it;
    loop = function*(){
        var i;
        for(i=1; i<=limit; i+=1){
            yield i;
        }
    };
    it = loop();
    return {
        start: function(){
            var timer = this;
            console.log('start');
            id = setInterval(function(){
                var tick = it.next();
                console.log(tick.value);
                if(tick.done){
                    timer.stop();
                    timer.reset();
                    return;
                }
            }, interval_ms);
        },
        stop: function(){
            console.log('stop');
            clearInterval(id);
        },
        reset: function(){
            console.log('reset');
            it = loop();
        }
    };
};

var t = maketimer();
t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
var x=0;
var myVar;
function myTimer() {
    x++;        
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = x;
    if(x==60)
        clearInterval(myVar);
}
function counter_start(){
    myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
 }
```