# Add a delay after executing each iteration with forEach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, delay, pause

Is there an easy way to slow down the iteration in a forEach (with plain javascript)? For example:

```
var items = document.querySelector('.item');

items.forEach(function(el) {
  // do stuff with el and pause before the next el;
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447407/whats-the-equivalent-of-javas-thread-sleep-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually trying to do this with plain javascript. I edited my question.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

What you want to achieve is totally possible with `Array#forEach` — although in a different way you might think of it. You can **not** do a thing like this:

```js
var array = ['some', 'array', 'containing', 'words'];
array.forEach(function (el) {
  console.log(el);
  wait(1000); // wait 1000 milliseconds
});
console.log('Loop finished.');
```

... and get the output:

```
some
array          // one second later
containing     // two seconds later
words          // three seconds later
Loop finished. // four seconds later
```

There is no synchronous `wait` or `sleep` function in JavaScript that blocks all code after it.

The only way to delay something in JavaScript is in a non–blocking way. That means using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or one of its relatives. We can use the second parameter of the function that we pass to `Array#forEach`: it contains the index of the current element:

```js
var array = ['some', 'array', 'containing', 'words'];
var interval = 1000; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?
array.forEach(function (el, index) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(el);
  }, index * interval);
});
console.log('Loop finished.');
```

Using the `index`, we can compute when the function should be executed. But now we have a different problem: the `console.log('Loop finished.')` is executed *before* the first iteration of the loop. That's because `setTimout` is non–blocking.

JavaScript sets the timeouts in the loop, but it doesn't wait for the timeouts to complete. It just continues executing the code after the `forEach`.

To handle that, we can use `Promise`s. Let's build a promise chain:

```js
var array = ['some', 'array', 'containing', 'words'];
var interval = 1000; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?
var promise = Promise.resolve();
array.forEach(function (el) {
  promise = promise.then(function () {
    console.log(el);
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, interval);
    });
  });
});

promise.then(function () {
  console.log('Loop finished.');
});
```

There is an excellent article about `Promise`s in conjunction with `forEach`/`map`/`filter` [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/basic-functional-programming-with-async-await.html).

---

I gets trickier if the array can change dynamically. In that case, I don't think `Array#forEach` should be used. Try this out instead:

```js
var array = ['some', 'array', 'containing', 'words'];
var interval = 2000; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?

var loop = function () {
  return new Promise(function (outerResolve) {
    var promise = Promise.resolve();
    var i = 0;
    var next = function () {
      var el = array[i];
      // your code here
      console.log(el);
      if (++i < array.length) {
        promise = promise.then(function () {
          return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              resolve();
              next();
            }, interval);
          });
        });
      } else {
        setTimeout(outerResolve, interval);
        // or just call outerResolve() if you don't want to wait after the last element
      }
    };
    next();
  });
};

loop().then(function () {
  console.log('Loop finished.');
});

var input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  // add the new item to the array
  array.push(input.value);
  input.value = '';
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Add to array</button>
```

Comment: This works great. Now, say the server was adding elements to the array while the promise loop was running. Is there an easy way - inside the loop - to query and append the array? Say it was var array = document.querySelectorAll('.all-at-the-moment-but-stay-tuned‌​');

Comment: Possible, but more complex.

Comment: shouldn't the resolve passed through the function be executed? :
    setTimeout(resolve(), interval);
Instead of :
   setTimeout(resolve, interval);

Comment: still works, was able to slow down a foreach that calls a client api that was complaining about how fast the calls were coming in.

Answer (score 10):

You need to make use of setTimeout to create a delay and have a recursive implementation

You example should look like

```js
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var i = 0;
(function loopIt(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
      // your code handling here
      console.log(items[i]);
      if(i < items.length - 1)  loopIt(i+1)
    }, 2000);
})(i)
```

Comment: That's just going to initialise all the timeouts in parallel. They'll execute more or less simulataneously. Also, the inner closure doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh my mistake, you are right. I edited my answer

Answer (score 9):

With JS Promises and `asnyc/await` syntax, you can make a `sleep` function that really works. However, `forEach` calls each iteration synchronously, so you get a 1 second delay and then all of the items at once.

```js
const items = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"];

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

items.forEach(async (item) => {
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log(item);
});
```

What we can do instead is use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` (or `setTimeout` but we're using the former) to make a timed forEach loop like so:

```js
function forEachWithDelay(array, callback, delay) {
  let i = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    callback(array[i], i, array);
    if (++i === array.length) clearInterval(interval);
  }, delay);
}

const items = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"];

forEachWithDelay(items, (item, i) => console.log(`#${i}: ${item}`), 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think recursion offers the simplest solution.

```
function slowIterate(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(arr[0]); // <-- replace with your custom code 
  setTimeout(() => {
    slowIterate(arr.slice(1));
  }, 1000); // <-- replace with your desired delay (in milliseconds) 
}

slowIterate(Array.from(document.querySelector('.item')));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async/await`, `Promise` constructor, `setTimeout()` and `for..of` loop to perform tasks in sequence where a `duration` can be set set before a task is performed

```js
(async() => {

  const items = [{
    prop: "a",
    delay: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001)
  }, {
    prop: "b",
    delay: 2500
  }, {
    prop: "c",
    delay: 1200
  }];

  const fx = ({prop, delay}) =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, prop)) // delay
    .then(data => console.log(data)) // do stuff

  for (let {prop, delay} of items) {
    // do stuff with el and pause before the next el;
    let curr = await fx({prop, delay});
  };
})();
```

Comment: @KirkRoss Note, the order of `//delay` , `// do stuff` at code can be adjusted to `//do stuff` , `// delay`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a promise and use it with a for, the example has to be in an async / await function:

```js
    let myPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        resolve('Count')
      }, 1000)
    })
  
    for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
      let count = await myPromise()
      console.log(`${count}: ${index}`)    
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The rest of the answers are overcomplicated.

You can simulate the "pause" in a loop in javascript using the "for" loop like the above code example by Sarten8.

Answer (score 1):

There are many complex answers, and most of them don't really solve this issue in an easy and straightforward way. Therefore, here a straightforward but "unpleasant" solution:

```js
const timestamp = new Date().getTime()

const items = ["1", "2", "3"]
items.forEach((item, index) => {
    console.log(item)
    
    // Loop until the index * 1000 milliseconds has passed
    while (new Date().getTime() < timestamp + index * 1000) {}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change your code:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item'), i;

for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  // items[i] <--- your element
}
```

> You can loop over Arrays easily in JavaScript with forEach, but
>   unfortunately, it's not that simple with the results of a
>   querySelectorAll

Read more about It [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/)

I can advice you to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) to find a right solution for sleep

Answer (score -1):

[Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

```
function* elGenLoop (els) {
  let count = 0;

  while (count < els.length) {
    yield els[count++];
  }
}

// This will also work with a NodeList
// Such as `const elList = elGenLoop(document.querySelector('.item'));`
const elList = elGenLoop(['one', 'two', 'three']);

console.log(elList.next().value); // one
console.log(elList.next().value); // two
console.log(elList.next().value); // three
```

This gives you complete control over when you want to access the next iteration in the list.