# Javascript Loop through Array while displaying the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a 'random selector' behaviour where the function iterates through an array for a period of time (example: 3 seconds, 5 seconds) while displaying all of array elements fast throughout the iteration until the iteration ends. Just imagine seeing all the elements displayed in a label one after another until it finally stops at an element.

My code so far:

```
var places = ["Curry Leaf", "Subway", "Burger King"];

function execute_randomizer() {
    var place_label = document.getElementById("place_label");
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var selected_place = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
        setTimeout(function () {
            place_label.innerText = selected_place;
        }, 400);
    }
}
```

This runs through the iteration and displays an element when the loop is done but it doesn't show each iteration's element. How can I amend this?

**EDIT**

Even if there's 3 elements, the animations must re-iterate through the array until the duration is completed

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45500721/5989584) very similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` finishes iterating before the `setTimeout` runs, then the function passed to `setTimeout` runs 100 times using the last value of `selected_place`.

More about this behavior in [setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)

---

Another problem that I noticed is that your setTimeout will trigger after 400ms, since the `for` loop will finish in about 1 ms, the function passed to `setTimeout` will trigger 100 times one after another with no delay in between, for this, I replaced the delay argument of setTimeout from `400` to `400 * i`.

---

```js
var places = ["Curry Leaf", "Subway", "Burger King"];     
function execute_randomizer() {
    var place_label = document.getElementById("place_label");
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var selected_place = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
        (function(selected_place){
          setTimeout(function () {
              place_label.innerText = selected_place;
          }, 400 * i);
        })(selected_place);
    }
}
execute_randomizer();
```

```html
<span id="place_label"></span>
```

Comment: This works but it looks quite glitchy. Anyway to make it smoother? If you know what I mean

Comment: @RickGrimesTheCoder I'm not sure I know what you mean, but if you use jQuery you could use some transition animations to make the replacement of text less "abrupt"

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure over the value and a different time for each timeout.

```js
var places = ["Curry Leaf", "Subway", "Burger King"];

function execute_randomizer() {
    var place_label = document.getElementById("place_label");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var selected_place = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
        setTimeout(function (value) {
            return function () {
                place_label.innerText = value;
            };
        }(selected_place), i * 100);
    }
}

execute_randomizer();
```

```html
<div id="place_label"></div>
```

For a first run through, you could show each element and then take a random element at last value.

```js
function execute_randomizer() {
    function cb (value) {
        return function () {
            place_label.innerText = value;
        };
    }

    var place_label = document.getElementById("place_label");

    place_label.innerText = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(cb(places[i]), 200 + i * 200);
    }
    setTimeout(cb(places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)]), 200 + places.length * 200);
}

var places = ["Curry Leaf", "Subway", "Burger King"];

execute_randomizer();
```

```html
<div id="place_label"></div>
```

Comment: How can I get rid of that glitchyness?

Comment: just take less elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your loop because right now you go in loop 100 times in maybe one millisecond and order `100` of change text but once again in the same time. 
So better is wait for time out `400 ms` and then make next iteration. 
Please remember time out is async.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better if you would put the whole function in a timeout. (I'm not sure and didn't test,  but that's what I would try).

What I mean is that you just build a function that creates your randomizer and fills in your field. After that you put a timeout to call the same function again + keep a counter that you pass as parameter.

An example of what I mean below: (didn't test it)

```
var places = ["Curry Leaf", "Subway", "Burger King"];

execute_randomizer(0); /* Start for the first time */

function execute_randomizer(times) {
    if(times == 100)
        return; /* stop execution */

    var place_label = document.getElementById("place_label");
    var selected_place = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
    place_label.innerText = selected_place;
    setTimeout(function () {
        execute_randomizer(times+1)
    }, 400);
}
```