# How to make forEach wait for subscribe to finish?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, async-await, subscribe

I'm using Angular 6 and my database is Firebase. Now I try to show each of the room's names according to its building. For example:

```
Building A
Room 1
Room 2
Building B
Room 1
Room 2
```

But every time I try, it will show all the building names first, and only then it will show the room's names. This is what I got for now:

```
Building A
Building B
Room 1
Room 2
```

I find out this happens because `forEach` keeps skipping the `subscribe` function.

I have attempted to use `promise` and `await`, but it doesn't work. Maybe because I use it in a wrong way? I'm not so sure how to use `promise` in a correct way.

```js
async loadData(){
    this.navigationService.user
        .subscribe( user => {
        console.log(user);
        this.user = user;
        this.navigationService.getBuildings(this.user.orgId)
            .subscribe( building => {
            this.navMasterBuilding = [];
            this.buildings = building;
            this.buildings.forEach( async building2 => {
                this.completeBuildingId = building2.completeBuildingId;
                this.buildingName = building2.buildingName;
                console.log(building2.buildingName);
                await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => { 
                    this.navigationService.getLocation(this.user.orgId, this.completeBuildingId)
                    .subscribe(location => {
                    console.log('room' + location);
                    this.navMasterLocation = [];
                    });
                    resolve();
                });   
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I have try to delay it by using setTimeout, but it still does't work.

Comment: Please add your code to the question not just a photo of your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498873/add-a-delay-after-executing-each-iteration-with-foreach-loop[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498873/add-a-delay-after-executing-each-iteration-with-foreach-loop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a delay after executing each iteration with forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498873/add-a-delay-after-executing-each-iteration-with-foreach-loop)

Comment: Tried `resolve();` under the inner subscription?

Comment: I have tried `resolve();` under the inner subscription, but it still does't work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try something like this me too have the same problem inside foreach and this is the solution i got https://stackblitz.com/edit/flatternstructure-rikbfs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Array.forEach` only works with synchronous functions. Change it to using the `for...of` syntax which does work. Next to that you `resolve` the `Promise` before the call to `getLocation` finished and the code in `subscribe` ran. Change the code to call `resolve` within the `getLocation.subscribe`.

```js
for(const building2 of buildings) {
    console.log(building2.buildingName);
    await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => { 
        this.navigationService.getLocation(this.user.orgId, this.completeBuildingId)
            .subscribe(location => {
                console.log('room' + location);
                this.navMasterLocation = [];

                resolve();
             });                    
    });   
}
```

Note that it can be simplified to:

```js
for(const building2 of buildings) {
    console.log(building2.buildingName);
    const location = await this.navigationService.getLocation(this.user.orgId, this.completeBuildingId).toPromise();
    console.log('room' + location);
    this.navMasterLocation = [];             
}
```

Also do note that I'm not quite sure why you use `this.completeBuildingId` instead of a local variable. Given that it gets overwritten in each iteration this seems a bit useless to me.

Comment: It work!!! Thanks David Walschots.. You just solved my problem.. By using `for ... of`  and move the resolve into inner subscribe it really works.. Thank you very much!