# How to delay a for loop and run canvas operation?

Tags: javascript, image, loops, canvas, delay

I would like to be run an iteration of a loop every x seconds.

Every iteration will change the value of a pixel and paint the changed image to the canvas.

So far I have this:

```
        for(let i=0;i<width;i++){ //Rows
          for(o=i*(width*4);o<i*(width*4)+(width*4);o+=4){//pixels in current row
                imgData.data[o] = 255
          }
          ctx.putImageData(imgData, xPos, yPos);
        }
```

Which successfully changes all pixels in the image to be 255 red. However, this happens all at the same time. I would like this to happen a pixel a time every x seconds.

Any guidance?

Comment: Did you try using a `setInterval()` event over the function ?

Comment: Set Interval doesnt work as the loop creates all the intervals at once and then they all fire after the time is up.

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498873/add-a-delay-after-executing-each-iteration-with-foreach-loop

Comment: @MatheusSimões This would create `(width * height)` / `imageData.data.length` `Promise`s. This might work for smaller collections but not for pixels in an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to happen a pixel every second you shouldn't use the outer for-loop at all.
Instead use a global variable which holds the position of the current pixel. With each interval increment that variable and put the changed imageData to the canvas.

Something like:

```js
var originalWidth = width;
var currentPixel = 0;

function update() {
  for (o = currentPixel * (originalWidth * 4); o < currentPixel * (originalWidth * 4) + (originalWidth * 4); o += 4) {
    imgData.data[o] = 255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, xPos, yPos);
  if (currentPixel + 1 < originalWidth) {
    currentPixel++
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}
var intervalId = setInterval(update, 1000);
```

Comment: Had to make a slight adjustment ,currentPixel += 4 was meant to be o+=4 if im not mistaken. Good answer though!

Comment: Outch - you're right! Sorry! I've overlooked that. It should have been o+=4

Answer (score 1):

A version with `setTimeout()` (or `requestAnimationFrame()`) and without the use of global variables (and without all the *"complicated"* math):

```
const modifyPixel = (function(canvas) {
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  return function(index = 0) {
    if (index >= imageData.data.length) {
      return;
    }

    imageData.data[index] = 255;
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    index += 4;

    setTimeout(function() {
      modifyPixel(index + 4);
    }, 50);
  };
}(document.querySelector("canvas")));
```

```js
(function init() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = "green";
  context.fill();
}());

const modifyPixel = (function(canvas) {
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  return function(index = 0) {
    if (index >= imageData.data.length) {
      return;
    }

    imageData.data[index] = 255;
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    
    index += 4;

    setTimeout(function() {
      modifyPixel(index + 4);
    }, 50);
  };
}(document.querySelector("canvas")));

modifyPixel();
```

```html
<canvas style="width:200px; height:200px" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>
```

Comment: My only concern with this it becomes a lot harder to customize down the line. a lot simpler though so +1