# Stop main/current thread and let callbacks finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

In essence I have a piece of code somewhat like:

```js
function closeServerGracefully() {
  setTimeout(process.exit, 1000);
}

if (failingCondition) {
  logger.log('error', 'Fatal error exiting because failingCondition', closeServerGracefully);
}

logger.log('info', 'Everything is ok!');
```

(The last argument to `logger.log` is a callback function that gets called after the message is logged, I'm using winston)

However, if `failingCondition` does in fact become true my app outputs this:

```
Fatal error exiting because failingCondition
Everything is ok!
```

Then of course it crashes a few moments later because the problem wasn't caught properly.

How can I stop (or pause or kill) the execution of the "main" thread after that `if` statement is entered?

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop main thread, you just can simulate "stop"

[What's the equivalent of Java's Thread.sleep() in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447407/whats-the-equivalent-of-javas-thread-sleep-in-javascript)

You can try to do it without stopping:

```
if (failingCondition) {
  logger.log('error', 'Fatal error exiting because failingCondition', closeServerGracefully);
} else {
  logger.log('info', 'Everything is ok!');
}
```

Comment: Obviously my example is short, I don't want to have to put the succeeding 1000+ lines of code into an else block

Comment: make else block an / lib / module / function etc.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

It is happening because the last log method is getting called before the timeout.

Things you can try:

You can try using a `else` there. So "Everything is ok!" will not logged if `failingCondition` is `true`.

If you are using this inside a method, you should try using a `return;` after `logger.log()` within the `if` block.

If you are trying to catch an exception, you should use a try/catch block.

Hope it helps!