# How to implement time intervals during execution of nested loops

Tags: javascript

I try to make an algorithm visualization project - right now I am implementing visualization of bubble-sort - I've got an array of arrays in which each outer array represents one iteration of the algorithm, and each inner array consists of boolean values - swap or no swap neighboring elements in the collection - I have algorithm ready, and sorting is done correctly, right now I wanted to introduce time delays between each swap - as it is visualization program I want the user to see actually what's going on. Here I stumbled upon a problem - I wanted to use async await with setTimeout but apparently I lack knowledge (I mostly work with java) - columns are not sorted correctly - I would say that setTimeout is incorrectly scheduled in parallel for different iterations, but I am not sure. Code of mine:

```
async function visualiseAlgorithm(responseFromServer) {
    for (const iteration of responseFromServer.data) {
        await displayIteration(iteration.swapsRecord);
    }
}

async function displayIteration(swapsForIteration) {
    let idx = 0;
    for (const shouldSwap of swapsForIteration) {
        await drawColumns(shouldSwap, idx++).then(res => {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawBaseLine();
            columnsArray.forEach(column => column.draw());
        });
    }
}

function drawColumns(toSwap, index){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        if(index > 1) columnsArray[index - 1].setColor("grey");
        let color;
        if(toSwap){
            color = "red";
            let temp = columnsArray[index].getHeight();
            columnsArray[index].setHeight(columnsArray[index + 1].getHeight());
            columnsArray[index + 1].setHeight(temp);
        }

    }, 100))
}
```

## Results:

#### With timeout and async await:

#### Input:

### [image]

#### Output

[image]

#### Without timeout and async await:

#### Input

[image]

#### Output

[image]

As requested: I post response from the server:

```
Array(37) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
0: Object { swapsRecord: [], collection: (45) […] }
1: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
2: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
3: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
4: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
5: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
6: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
7: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
8: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
9: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
10: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
11: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
12: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
13: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
14: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
15: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
16: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
17: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
18: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
19: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
20: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
21: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
22: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
23: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
24: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
25: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
26: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
27: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
28: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
29: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
30: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
31: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
32: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
33: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
34: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
35: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
36: Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
```

Objects in the array consists of: (the collection array is redundant and not used - I plan to delete it)

```
Object { swapsRecord: (44) […], collection: (45) […] }
collection: Array(45) [ 61, 53, 35, … ]
swapsRecord: Array(44) [ false, true, true, … ]
0: false
1: true
​​​2: true
​​​3: false
​​​4: true
​​​5: true
​​​6: true
​​​7: false
​​​8: true
​​​9: true
​​​10: true
​​​11: true
​​​12: true
​​​13: true
​​​14: true
​​​15: true
​​​16: true
​​​17: true
​​​18: true
​​​19: true
​​​20: true
​​​21: true
​​​22: true
​​​23: true
​​​24: true
​​​25: true
​​​26: true
​​​27: true
​​​28: true
29: true
​​​30: true
​​​31: true
​​​32: true
​​​33: true
​​​34: true
​​​35: true
​​​36: true
​​​37: true
​​​38: true
​​​39: true
​​​40: false
​​​41: true
​​​42: true
​​​43: true
​​​length: 44
```

Comment: Why is async await required here? There is no asynchronous operation in `drawColumns` or `displayIteration`

Comment: Can you please post a sample of `responseFromServer.data`? You probably just need `100 * index)` for delay and remove all async await code

Comment: @adiga - I considered this approach - if I understand you correctly: flat mapping iterations and swapRecords and then iterating through this big array (size: swapRecords.size * array.size) - but I discarded it for two reasons: 
1. I want to understand better async await
2. Parsing through iterations would be in my opinion, not the best practice - there are more elements in the collection than swapRecords and I think it would be ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve the promise or it wouldn't do the following stuff. Without it, your loop will stay the first step.

That's the reason why the output is the same as the input.

```js
async function visualiseAlgorithm(responseFromServer) {
    for (const iteration of responseFromServer.data) {
        await displayIteration(iteration.swapsRecord);
    }
}

async function displayIteration(swapsForIteration) {
    let idx = 0;
    for (const shouldSwap of swapsForIteration) {
        await drawColumns(shouldSwap, idx++).then(res => {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawBaseLine();
            columnsArray.forEach(column => column.draw());
        });
    }
}

function drawColumns(toSwap, index){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        if(index > 1) columnsArray[index - 1].setColor("grey");
        let color;
        if(toSwap){
            color = "red";
            let temp = columnsArray[index].getHeight();
            columnsArray[index].setHeight(columnsArray[index + 1].getHeight());
            columnsArray[index + 1].setHeight(temp);
        }
        // this is the point
        resolve()
    }, 100))
}
```

For more information
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `sleep` function like this. And, `await` it whenever you want a delay. This will avoid the superfluous async and Promise wrappers in existing `drawColumns` function

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092642
async function sleep(sec) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, sec));
}

async function visualiseAlgorithm(responseFromServer) {
  for (const iteration of responseFromServer.data) {
    await displayIteration(iteration.swapsRecord);
  }
}

async function displayIteration(swapsForIteration) {
  let idx = 0;
  for (const shouldSwap of swapsForIteration) {
    await sleep(100) // <-- add this whenever you want a delay

    drawColumns(shouldSwap, idx++)
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBaseLine();
    columnsArray.forEach(column => column.draw());
  }
}

function drawColumns(toSwap, index) {
  if (index > 1) columnsArray[index - 1].setColor("grey");
  let color;
  if (toSwap) {
    color = "red";
    let temp = columnsArray[index].getHeight();
    columnsArray[index].setHeight(columnsArray[index + 1].getHeight());
    columnsArray[index + 1].setHeight(temp);
  }
}
```