# When does setTimeout start counting down?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

Here's the code I'm working with right now:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 2000);
for (let i  = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
   console.log("printing...")
}
setTimeout(() => console.log('second'), 1000);
```

### Expectation (`setTimeout` starts counting down right away)

1. The first `setTimeout` will execute and start the timer for 2000 ms. However, since `setTimeout` callbacks are ran asynchronously, we'll have to skip over it and wait for the full call stack to finish before going through the callback queue.
2. Go through the `for` loop. From my computer, it took around ~20 seconds for the whole `for` loop to finish running. Around a few seconds into the `for` loop, the first `setTimeout` should be done with it's timer now.
3. The second `setTimeout` will then execute and start the timer. Similar to the first step
4. Now that the call stack is done running, we go through the callback queue. Since the first `setTimeout` should've finished the delay first despite the higher delay, it should print `"first"` then `"second"`

### Actual

```
printing...
/* Lots of "printing..." strings */
printing...
second
first
```

Seems to be the case that the second `setTimeout` still runs first. In this case, does this mean that the `setTimeout` countdowns only begin after the initial few lines of code are ran? I've tested this code on both Firefox and Chrome, and they seem to have the same behavior.

Comment: Yes, the second timeout runs first, it fires about a second earlier than the first timeout. The countdown starts immediately after `setTimeout` itself has been executed. Notice, that iterating a 5000 length loop takes only a few milliseconds.

Comment: I see no way how `for (let i  = 0; i < 5000; i++) { console.log("printing...") }` would take *20 seconds*. The printing perhaps but that doesn't mean the *loop* takes 20 seconds.

Comment: 5000 iterations shouldn't take more than a few ms. I assume that the tool you are using is falls behind on the printing. If you take [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4utomr3y/) example, if you open the developer tools console, you can see that it has already finished there, before it has finished printing it on the webpage itself.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now. The `console.log` is misleading. It looks like the loop takes longer than it actually takes. WIthout `console.log` it behaves as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/4utomr3y/1/

Comment: So to clarify, the for loop actually is finished, it's just that printing the strings onto the console is what takes the long time? Running the code on JSFiddle for me takes a decent time for the for loop to finish, but if the delay is just with the printing, that makes sense.

As a followup, would that mean given 2 `setTimeout`s that are spaced between code that runs for a long enough time, is it possible for the first `setTimeout` (Given it has a longer delay than the second one) to print before the second one?

Comment: If the loop really takes that long, the code works as you expect, the first timeout callback will be called first.

Comment: @seeingstars It appears to be so. You can verify by adding `Date()` as a second argument to your `console.log` calls - that'll run when the code is executed, regardless how much later it is printed

Comment: "*Running the code on JSFiddle for me takes a decent time for the for loop to finish,*" no, *the loop* finishes in quite fast. However *printing* takes longer. You're probably looking at the console *in the page*. And "printing" there means updating the DOM which takes a lot longer than in an actual console. You're not actually measuring the correct thing - DOM updates aren't what the code does. Open your browser console to see the difference. https://jsfiddle.net/0hy7qr1n/

Comment: You could replace the for loop with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447407/whats-the-equivalent-of-javas-thread-sleep-in-javascript#answer-16077558) to more accurately approximate the desired delay

Comment: @VLAZ The browser console is also a DOM which takes a long time to update

Comment: *"You can verify by adding `Date()` as a second argument to your console.log calls - that'll run when the code is executed, regardless how much later it is printed"*

Wow, adding a `Date()` made it so much clearer as to what happens in the code. Thank you so much for this suggestion! That solves the question for me!

Comment: @Bergi I'm using FF and all the prints resolve before the `"loop ended..."` message in the browser console.

Comment: @VLAZ What "loop ended"? But all I meant to say is that the console may also take a longer time to print than the code takes to execute. Given that this is typically asynchronous, it won't block anything, and you'll of course get all your outputs in the expected order, but possibly delayed.

Comment: @Bergi ```console.log(`loop ended in ${performance.now() - start} ms`);``` is in the JSFiddle link I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is correct, but the provided sample is deceptive. The for-loop does not take ~20 seconds. JavaScript finishes way sooner. It might take the JavaScript container (like your Browser) around 20 seconds to print everything, but the script just continues on.

```js
//    [------ unit definition ------]  [--------- alias --------]
const MILLISECOND =    1             , MILLISECONDS = MILLISECOND;
const SECOND      = 1000*MILLISECONDS, SECONDS      = SECOND     ;

setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 2*SECONDS);

console.log("starting heavy work");
const start = Date.now();
for (let i  = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
   console.log("printing...");
}
console.log(`finished work in ${(Date.now() - start)/SECONDS}s`);

setTimeout(() => console.log('second'), 1*SECOND);
```

`setTimeout(() => console.log('second'), 1*SECOND)` is executed less than a second after `setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 2*SECONDS)`. You can see how long the loop actually takes by comparing the start and end time of the loop.

Here is an example of some code that is actually busy for about 5 seconds.

```js
//    [------ unit definition ------]  [--------- alias --------]
const MILLISECOND =    1             , MILLISECONDS = MILLISECOND;
const SECOND      = 1000*MILLISECONDS, SECONDS      = SECOND     ;


setTimeout(() => console.log("first"), 2*SECONDS);

console.log("starting heavy work");
const start = Date.now();
while (Date.now() - start < 5*SECONDS); // block the script for 5 seconds
console.log(`finished work in ${(Date.now() - start)/SECONDS}s`);

setTimeout(() => console.log("second"), 1*SECOND);
```