# Can I have a setTimeout inside a handler of another setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Here's a quick (broke) jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wH2qF/

This isn't working for some reason... is it because I have a setTimeout inside a handler of another setTimeout?

```
$(function() {
   $("#Volume").click(function() {
      setTimeout(triggerVolumeChange, 4000);
      function triggerVolumeChange() 
      {
          var volumeDiv = document.getElementById("volumeNumber");
          var volumeOld = 8;
          var volumeNew = 37;
          var timeNew = (1000/(volumeNew-volumeOld));
          changeVolume();
                        
          function changeVolume()
          {
             volumeDiv.innerHTML = volumeOld;
             volumeOld++;
             if (volumeOld <= volumeNew) setTimeout(changeVolume, timeNew);
          };
      });
});
```

Should specify that for clarity purposes I deleted other things from that Click function, and also to clarify what doesn't work exactly, well, basically, I click and nothing happens, whereas if I cut out this chunk of code it works fine... actually the setting of the vars also work fine (naturally I presume) but when I paste or uncomment the changeVolume() function then the click stops working again... Any thoughts?

--

Another piece of clarification: What I'm trying to do is, on click, simulate the volume going from value 8 to 37, in a string.. thus the setTimeout inside that function.

--

As per your guy's request, here's the entire code... I doubt it will make sense, but here it is... FYI, on click this will trigger a number of animations to simulate the flow of an application I'm designing..

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $("#Volume").click(function() {
                                        
                    var userPrompt = document.getElementById("userPrompt")
                    userPrompt.innerHTML = "Change volume to 37";
                                        
                    var avatarIcon = document.getElementById("avatarIcon");
                    avatarIcon.innerHTML = "<img src='imgs/haloIcons-volume_82x76.png' alt='Volume'/>";
                
                    var hints = document.getElementById("hints");
                    hints.style.opacity = 0;
                    $(".dragonTvOut").toggleClass("dragonTvIn");
                    
                    setTimeout(triggerP, 1000);
                    function triggerP()
                    {
                        var halo = document.getElementById('avatar');
                        if( 'process' in halo ) { 
                            halo.process();
                        };
                    };
                    
                    setTimeout(triggerUserPrompt, 2000);
                    function triggerUserPrompt() 
                    {
                        document.getElementById("userPrompt").className = "userPromptIn";
                    };
                    
                    setTimeout(triggerVolumeChange, 4000);
                    function triggerVolumeChange() 
                    {
                        document.getElementById("userPrompt").className = "userPromptEnd";
                        
                        var halo = document.getElementById('avatar');
                        if( 'resume' in halo ) { 
                            halo.resume();
                        }

                        document.getElementById("avatarIcon").className = "avatarIconEnd";
                        
                        var volumeDiv = document.getElementById("volumeNumber");
                        var volumeOld = 8;
                        var volumeNew = 37;
                        var timeNew = (1000/(volumeNew-volumeOld));
                        changeVolume();
                        
                        function changeVolume()
                        {
                            volumeDiv.innerHTML = volumeOld;
                            volumeOld++;
                            if (volumeOld <= volumeNew) setTimeout(changeVolume, timeNew);
                        }​;
                        
                        var side = 100;
                        var paper = new Raphael(volumeArcAnim, 100, 300);
                        
                        paper.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {

                            var alpha = 360 / total * value,
                                a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
                                x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
                                y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
                                path;
                            if (total == value) {
                                path = [
                                    ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                                    ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
                                ];
                            } else {
                                path = [
                                    ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                                    ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
                                ];
                            }
                            return {
                                path: path
                            };
                        };
                    
                        var arcWidth = 87;
                        var strokeRadius = arcWidth/2;
                        
                        var indicatorArc = paper.path().attr({
                            "stroke": "#ffffff",
                            "stroke-width": 3,
                            arc: [side/2, side/2, 12, 100, strokeRadius]
                        });
                        
                        indicatorArc.animate({
                            arc: [side/2, side/2, 60, 100, strokeRadius]
                        }, 1500, "<>", function(){
                            // anim complete here
                        });
                        
                    };
                                            
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? I think `setTimeout()` takes a string for the method call.

Comment: @Knownasilya - It takes a string or a function.

Comment: @Knownasilya [never pass strings to setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797115/settimeout-how-to-avoid-using-string-for-callback).

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: you might want to consider refactoring your functions in such a way that they pass parameters to each other rather than relying on executing in the parent function's scope.

Comment: It seems most likely the code just contains a syntax error. If the code above isn't the actual code can you paste the actual code so we can check it?  Alternatively just use the browsers debugging tool to step through it and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: but it works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/JzyYw/2/

Comment: @jbabey because it's deprecated? At least that's what I get from MDN.

Comment: @Knownasilya a few reasons: it has to `eval` your string, which is known to be a bad practice for its own reasons. also, it forces your "code" (string) to be executed in the global context which, in examples such as the OPs code, would break the code (neither `triggerVolumeChange` nor `changeVolume` would be defined in the global context)

Comment: pasted the entire code above...

Comment: does having the entire code above help? does anyone find any red flags?

Comment: @user1810062 It will be more helpful to create a working (broken) example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Juan Mendes, here it is... http://jsfiddle.net/wH2qF/

Comment: just to compare... this works: http://jsfiddle.net/7rGSb/ this does not http://jsfiddle.net/wH2qF/

Comment: @ttothec Please see my answer and comment on it, the jsfiddle you added pretty much works

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can have a `setTimeout()` inside another one -- this is the typical mechanism used for repeating timed events.

The reason yours isn't working is not to do with the `setTimeout()` itself; it's to do with the way you've nested the functions.

The `changeVolume()` function being inside `triggerVolumeChange()` means that you can't reference it directly using its name.

The quickest solution for you would be to remove the nesting, so that `changeVolume()` is at the root level rather than nested inside `triggerVolumeChange()`.

Comment: Your comment about it being actually `triggerVolumeChange.changeVolume` is not correct. It is true that `changeVolume` is only accessible inside `triggerVolumeChange` so it's likely the problem here. I'd upvote this if you fixed/clarified that part

Comment: @JuanMendes - Sure, I'll amend it. I know it can't be called that way (hence that wasn't my advice); I was trying to point out how it fitted into the namespace the way it was written rather than how it would be called.

Comment: Any ideas on how to "convert" that function to work in the root of `triggerVolumeChange()`

Comment: Hmmm... When moving `changeVolume()` out of `triggerVolumeChange()` also makes all variables used in `changeVolume()` undefined, since they will be out of the scope...

Comment: mmm... actually, `changeVolume` is not referenced outside of `triggerVolumeChange`?

Comment: @JuanMendes Not as it is in the post, but according Spudley's answer, it should be taken away from the original scope...

Comment: Hey guys I went ahead and put this on a jsfiddle... any help?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing an `}`:

```
$(function() {
   $("#Volume").click(function() {
      setTimeout(triggerVolumeChange, 4000);
      function triggerVolumeChange()
      {
          var volumeDiv = document.getElementById("volumeNumber");
          var volumeOld = 8;
          var volumeNew = 37;
          var timeNew = (1000/(volumeNew-volumeOld));
          changeVolume();

          function changeVolume()
          {
             volumeDiv.innerHTML = volumeOld;
             volumeOld++;
                 if (volumeOld <= volumeNew) setTimeout(changeVolume, timeNew);
          };
      } // that one was missing
   });
});
```

Comment: This was most likely due to me copying from my code. I'm not missing any } on my code...

Answer (score 3):

In your broken example http://jsfiddle.net/wH2qF/ there are a few problems

- You forgot to tell jsfiddle to use jQuery
- The id of the volume span (in JS) was `ph` but should be `volumeNumber` (as in the HTML)

[Click here to see a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/wH2qF/8/)

Had you selected jQuery from the libraries in jsfiddle, you would have seen an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

That leads me to believe that your jsfiddle is not a good representation of your problem. Maybe try to create another reduction since the one you added only had "silly" errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `setInterval()`, you can make the code work with these changes:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Volume").click(function() {
        setTimeout(triggerVolumeChange, 4000);
        function triggerVolumeChange () {
            var volumeDiv = document.getElementById("volumeNumber");
            var volumeOld = 8;
            var volumeNew = 37;
            var timeNew = (1000/(volumeNew-volumeOld));
            var changeVolume = function () {
                volumeDiv.innerHTML = volumeOld;
                volumeOld++;
                if (volumeOld <= volumeNew) setTimeout(changeVolume, timeNew);
            };
            changeVolume();
        }
    });
});
```

Working demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6ynJ/).

Comment: I've copied your code to a jsfiddle and it's not working... http://jsfiddle.net/wH2qF/2/ any ideas as to why?

Comment: @ttothec I've no clue... I tested the code locally before posting it, and it worked well :(.

Comment: @ttothec OK, it works now, just select `jQuery` from Framework panel in your fiddle. Thanks to Juan Mendez for a tip : ).

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no difference where the timer is initiated from. In most cases it is implemented as list of the timers with an identifiers and associated callback handlers.

So it will be ok if your logic is correct. There is no unpredictable conditions that bring infinite call sequences, and there is no infinite amount of timeout instances and so on.

For example imitation of `setInterval` function:

```js
// Bad (unexpected multiple sequences started per each event)

const handler = () => {
  setTimeout(handler)
}

<Button onClick={handler} />
```

```js
// Good (previous interval closed before start new one)

const [id, idUpdate] = useState(-1)

const handler = () => {
  const id = setTimeout(handler)
  idUpdate(id)
}

const start = () => {
  if(id !===-1) clearTimeout(id)
  idUpdate(-1)
  handler()
}

<Button onClick={start} />
```

or some else

```js
// Bad (infinite events with small time will take all cpu time)

const handler = () => {
  setTimeout(handler, 0) // actually mean several ms
}
```

```js
// Good (special condition for finish iterations)

let count = 20

const handler = () => {
  if(!count) return
  count--
  setTimeout(handler, 0)
}
```